# How to create a image slider with zooming functionality with responsive in react native for Android

Tags: android, react-native, carousel, zooming, react-native-image

Currently I am using these 2 libraries

```
import ImageZoom from 'react-native-image-pan-zoom';
import Carousel from 'react-native-snap-carousel';
```

ImageZoom for zooming the image and Carousel for sliding the images.

but I cannot make it this as responsive, how to do that?

This is my code:-

```
  <ImageZoom
      cropWidth={400}
      cropHeight={400}
      imageWidth={400}
      imageHeight={400}
      minScale={1}
      maxScale={3}
      style={{ resizeMode: 'contain', width: '100%' }}
    >
      <Image
        source={{ uri: image url }}
        style={styles.image}
        resizeMode={'cover'}
      />
  </ImageZoom>
```